# Error: Did not find the <extensions> element Error on Installing FUSE in JBossEAP 7.2

Tags: java, jboss, jbossfuse, jboss-eap-7

I follow the steps to install the JBossEAP based on the JBoss documentation. Then downloaded the patch from following [JBoss resource location](https://access.redhat.com/jbossnetwork/restricted/softwareDetail.html?softwareId=67631) and installed it successfully. FYI I setup JDK 8 for this JBoss EAP.

[Patch successful installation output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Naw.png)

Then verified the patch version after installation.

Then downloaded the compatible FUSE version from [JBoss EAP resources](https://access.redhat.com/jbossnetwork/restricted/softwareDetail.html?softwareId=63521&product=jboss.fuse&version=7.02.0&downloadType=distributions).

After that based on the [JBossEAP installation guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.2/html/installing_on_jboss_eap/installing_red_hat_jboss_fuse_on_eap) I installed the jar file in JBossEAP folder using below command.

java -jar C:\Personal\Coding\SW\FUSE\jboss-eap-7.2.0\jboss-eap-7.2\fuse-eap-installer-7.2.0.fuse-720018-redhat-00002.jar

However I got following error after execution of the command.

[Error message get after installing JBossEAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu7bb.png)

**Error: Did not find the  element
Error: Command did not terminate normally**

Does anyone experience this kind of error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the JBoss EAP documentation, it is recommended to install JBoss FUSE 7.4 on JBoss EAP 7.2. Please note that JBoss FUSE 7.2 is not compatible with JBoss EAP 7.2.
So to resolve this issue

1. Install JBoss EAP 7.2(Fresh installation)
2. Then download the [JBoss FUSE 7.4 from JBoss website](https://access.redhat.com/jbossnetwork/restricted/softwareDetail.html?softwareId=71551&product=jboss.fuse&version=7.04.0&downloadType=distributions) and then install JBoss fuse using following command

java -jar C:\JARS\fuse-eap-installer-7.4.0.jar

For more details,

kindly consult the documentation.
https://access.redhat.com/articles/310603#Red-Hat-Fuse-74